# Deciphering an unknown character encoding

Tags: unicode, encoding, reverse-engineering, filemaker

I am trying to understand the string character encoding of a proprietary file format (`fp7`-file format from [Filemaker Pro](https://www.filemaker.com/)).

1. I found that each character is obfuscated by `XOR` with `0b01011010` and that the string length is encoded using a single starting byte (max string length in Filemaker is 100 characters).
2. Encoding is a variable byte encoding, where by default ISO 8859-1 (Western) is used to encode most characters.
3. If a unicode character outside ISO 8859-1 is to be encoded, some sort of `control characters` are included into the string that modify the decoding of the next or several following characters. These control characters are using the ASCII control character space (`0x01` to `0x1f` in particular). This is were I am stuck, as I can't seem to find a pattern to how these control characters work.

Some examples of what I think I have found:

- When encountering a control character `0x11` the following characters are created by adding `0x40` to the byte value, e.g. the character `Ā` (Unicode `\U0100`) is encoded as `0x11 0xC0` (`0xC0` + `0x40` = `0x100`).
- When encountering the control character `0x10` the previous control character seems to be reset.
- When encountering the control character `0x03` the next (only the next!) character is created by adding `0x100` to the byte value. If the control character `0x03` is preceeded by `0x1b` then all following characters are created by adding `0x100`.

An example string (`0_ĀĐĠİŀŐŠŰƀƐƠưǀǐǠǰȀ`), its unicode code points and the encoding in Filemaker:

```
   char   0  _      Ā   Đ   Ġ   İ      ŀ      Ő      Š      Ű         ƀ   Ɛ   Ơ   ư   ǀ   ǐ   Ǡ   ǰ         Ȁ  
unicode  30 5f    100 110 120 130    140    150    160    170       180 190 1a0 1b0 1c0 1d0 1e0 1f0       200
encoded  30 5f 11  c0  d0  e0  f0  3  40  3  50  3  60  3  70 1b  3  80  90  a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  f0 1c  4  80
```

As you can see the characters `0` and `_` are encoded with their direct unicode/ASCII value. The characters `ĀĐĠİ` are encoded using the `0x11` control byte. Then `ŀŐŠŰ` are encoded using `0x03` for each character, then `0x1B 0x03` are used to encode the next 8 characters, etc.

**Does this encoding scheme look familiar to anybody?**

The rules are simple for characters up to 0x200, but then become more and more confusing, even to the point where they seem position dependent.

I can provide more examples for a weekend of puzzles and joy.

Comment: I can’t answer your question directly, but can I ask you what you want to accomplish by decoding this format? Seems like an awful lot of work when almost everything in the file is accessible in other ways.

Comment: There is suprising little information and open source tools available for the fileformat. At this point it is just some intellectual curiosity and a slight itch to automate some repetitive tasks regarding table / field management in FMP.

Comment: You should know that the fp7 format is for version up to 11 and is deprecated. We are now at version 17 and fmp12 format is in use since version 12. I assume you are aware of the DDR report available for any file? On the Mac, there is AppleScript support and on Windows some VBscript support. Several options exist with custom web publishing, such as PHP and XML. ODBC and the new Data API are other options.

Comment: As for tools, you are right. The format is not public knowledge and very few have bothered to dissect it. One exception is the FMdiff tool which compares files without using the DDR like other tools do. Maybe you can learn something from this. http://www.fmdiff.com

Comment: Two side notes: **1.** If you need to perform "repetitive tasks regarding table / field management" then you're doing something wrong. A  database schema should be more or less constant, and repetitive tasks should involve data only. Such tasks are easily automated using the tools provided by the application. -- **2.** FileMaker files are notoriously susceptible to corruption even in normal course of operations; I would not trust any tool that attempts to tamper directly with the actual file contents.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts! I have contact the author of fmdiff to see if he is willing to help.